# Show bootstrap modal after successful save to db

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic email entry form on my home page, and if the subscriber's email is saved I want to redirect them back and display a bootstrap modal. I've thought about sending a `flash[]` or `session[]` to the view and then saying, "If `flash / session`, display modal," but I'm not sure how to actually trigger the modal.

Basically, I'm wondering two things:

- How to tell the view that the DB insert was successful.
- How to trigger the bootstrap modal using this info.

*/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb:*

```
def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save
    # Send info to view (a flash?) saying to show modal
    redirect_to root_path
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add flash message on redirect:

`flash[:success] = 'Successfully subscribed"`

Add on the view end use this condition to show the modal box automatically:

```
<% if flash[:success] == 'Successfully subscribed' %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
 </script>
<% end %>
```

FYI: "#myModal" is the ID of your modal box

Comment: Thanks. Modified this slightly by putting the JS in a separate file and using and rendering a partial view with the modal (e.g. `<%= render "layouts/layout" %>`).

Comment: Yeah thats great! I was just give you the idea. :)